# How to create slice of LPM trie record for IPs/CIDRs

Tags: go, ip, trie, ebpf

I am trying to use the `BatchUpdate` and `BatchDelete` API from https://github.com/cilium/ebpf/blob/master/map.go#L952-L1038. from my understanding, I need to create slice of LPM trie of IPs/CIRDs, for example: if I have `denyIPs := []string{"10.11.15.114/32", "127.0.0.1/32"}`, I need to convert the `denyIPs` to slice of LPM trie, I google searched and unable to find example I can learn (still newbie to Golang). my intention is to replace my
https://github.com/vincentmli/xdp-firewall/blob/main/main.go#L78-L102 with batch update and delete.

Comment: I just found out the `BatchDelete` calls `marshalBytes` which seems does not handle case `[]string`, does it mean I do need to convert []string to []byte and handle the endian order before feeding to `BatchDelete`? not sure how to do that

Comment: I think I need to create slice of golang LPM trie struct for input to `BatchDelete`, my sample code of []byte for single delete kind of leading me to wrong thinking of [][]byte to `BatchDelete`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supplying Go strings in unparsed format. The key of an LPM trie must always follow

```c
struct bpf_lpm_trie_key {
    __u32   prefixlen;  /* up to 32 for AF_INET, 128 for AF_INET6 */
    __u8    data[0];    /* Arbitrary size */
};
```

So the first 4 bytes must contain your prefix as a 32-bit unsigned integer. Followed by in your case the 4 bytes of your IPv4 address. So you will have to do some parsing of your strings.

The eBPF library can marshal structs, so the easiest way to go is to define a struct for your key:

```golang
type MapKey struct {
  Prefix  uint32
  Address [4]byte
}
```

Then provide a slice of these map keys `[]MapKey` to the batch functions.

Comment: Yes I did something similar but still get invalid argument from the library, maybe I did something wrong, will try again

Comment: Hi Dylan, here is my sample code https://github.com/vincentmli/xdp-firewall/tree/go-lpm-trie, with that, I got "BatchUpdate: batch update: invalid argument", I think I may did something wrong with https://github.com/vincentmli/xdp-firewall/blob/go-lpm-trie/main.go#L48-L62 cause it did not address the endian order like I did to the single key/map update

Comment: The batch functions on LPM tries are only supported since kernel v5.13, before that only single key operations work. So also make sure your kernel has support.

Comment: Thanks Dylan, it is working now, I copied the code from cilium egressgateway map without proper adjusting the prefix length, change `key.PrefixLen = PolicyStaticPrefixBits + uint32(ones)` to `uint32(ones)` resolved the issue